# In which country do you pay tax and duty when travelling through multiple countries?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, uk-citizens, asia, taxes

In example, my journey would look in the order: Vietnam, Hong Kong, Philippines, Singapore, Malaysia, Thailand and back to the UK.

How the customs duty and taxes work?
Do you pay in the next country which you're entering (Buying in Vietnam, you pay import taxes in Hong Kong, buying in Hong Kong - you pay taxes in Philippines), or at the end of your journey when back to the UK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the way it works is that you pay duty when you import something permanently to a country. If you are visiting a country, you generally do not pay import duty on something you are bringing in temporarily. That's why you don't have to pay duty on things you bring with you when you visit a country as a tourist.

The issue is that they have to believe that, if you are visiting for a short time, you will be taking these things out again when you leave. If you arrive with one laptop and one phone, that both look used, they don't usually worry. If you arrive with three laptops still in their boxes they will expect you to prove that they are not going to be imported.

Some countries might make you register the things you bring in, and/or pay a deposit which is returnable when you take the things out again. The only way to find out for sure is to check the rules of each country you are visiting